# logical operators in python sets

Tags: python, set

im curious about how the logical operators work in sets. cosider this:

```
x = set('abcde')
y = set('bdxyz')

# union
print(x | y) # output: {'d', 'b', 'y', 'e', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'a'}
print(x or y) # output: {'d', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'a'} 

# intersection
print(x and y) # output: {'d', 'b', 'y', 'z', 'x'}
print(x & y) # output: {'b', 'd'}
```

i expected the outputs for union and intersection to be the same for each. how is it possible that they are not? can anyone explain?

Comment: Because the bitwise operators are distinct from the boolean logical operators, I don't know why you *expected* them to be the same. Also, your output is incorrect for the union. The logical operator should be first

Comment: This has nothing to do with the operands being `set`s.  This is how `and` and `or` work for all types. Try `1 or 2` and `50 or 0`.

Comment: `x or y` is not the same as `x | y`. The latter is the the union for sets. The former is saying return the first Truthy value.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that `or` and `&` produce expected output while `|` and `and` don't. I'd think it'd be one pair or another.

Comment: @ggorlen that just happens to be the case.

Comment: @MatthewStory actually, it doesn't--OP just typed it in wrong: https://repl.it/repls/BaggyAmusedBlock

Comment: @ggorlen ah .. :shrug:, in any case these operators have no relationship to one-another.

Comment: @MatthewStory I agree. I was mostly sucked in to this post because of the inconsistent output. If Python actually worked that way, I'd barf. It's very upsetting.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot override the functionality of logical `and` and `or` in python. So when you call:

```
>>> set([1, 2, 3]) or set([2, 3, 4])
{1, 2, 3}
```

It's treating it as logical or, which would evaluate the left side to boolean true and immediately stops evaluating and returns the left side. Similarly:

```
>>> set([1, 2, 3]) and set([2, 3, 4])
{2, 3, 4}
```

Is treated as a logical `and`, which would evaluate the left side to boolean `True` and then evaluate the right side to boolean `True` resulting in the right side being returned.

Logical `and` and `or` have no relationship to bitwise `&` and `|` in any language, python included.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's better to illustrate with an example.

`or` returns the first value that evaluates as True

```
# any non-zero integer is True
1 or 0 => 1
0 or 1 or 2 => 1
0 or 0 or 2 => 2
```

since non-empty set `x` is evaluated as True

```
x or y => x  which is {'d', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'a'}
```

Meanwhile `and` need to evaluate all the expressions and only when all the expressions are evaluated as True, it returns the last one.

```
1 and 2 => 2
1 and 'a' and (1, 2, 3) => (1, 2, 3)
```

since both `x` and `y` can be evaluated as True

```
x and y => y  which is {'d', 'b', 'y', 'z', 'x'}
```