# usage of `OR, AND` operators in set union

Tags: python, set

Bear with me if the question is duplicate. But cant seem to find any related questions/solutions.

Suppose I have tow sets:

```
set_one = {10,5,7}
set_two = {10,1,3,6, 5, 7}
set_one | set_two # union of two sets
{1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10}
set_one.union(set_two) # same as above
{1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10}
```

Why does  using `or` result in intersection instead of union? check below

```
set_one or set_two # union of two sets
{10, 5, 7} # Shouldn't this be {1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10}?
```

And using `and` results in union instead of intersection?

```
set_one & set_two # intersection of two sets
{5, 7, 10}
set_one.intersection(set_two) # same as above
{5, 7, 10}
set.intersection(set_one, set_two) # same as above
{5, 7, 10}
```

Using `and`

```
set_one and set_two
{1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10} # Should'n this be {5, 7, 10}
```

Run this on python 3.11.5

Comment: `and` and `&` are entirely different operators, similar to how in many languages `&&` is a boolean AND and `&` is a bitwise intersection.

Comment: What makes you think that `or` is intersection? `{1, 2} or {3, 4} == {1, 2}` which is not intersection.

Comment: `{1, 2} and {3, 4} == {3, 4}` which is not union.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564738/logical-operators-in-python-sets - although _not_ IMO of the question that that one is marked as a duplicate of, since that discusses bitwise operations on integers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do "and" and "or" act with non-boolean values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`or` and `and` are logical (boolean) operators, they don't operate differently on sets. You're observing their short-circuiting behavior here - `x or y` is just `x` if `x` is true in a boolean context, which any non-empty set is. And `x and y` is `y` if `x` is true.

Comment: It's common to use the terms "truthy" and "falsey" to mean "true/false in a boolean context".

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately, yes. But the official terminology is true/false.

Comment: Sorry for even asking the question. Lack of sleep. I completely forgot of the short circuiting haha. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

Neither is the case.  If you use an example where the union and intersection don't happen to be equal to one of the original two sets, that makes the difference between `or`, `and`, `|`, and `&` much plainer:

```
>>> set_one = {1, 2, 3}
>>> set_two = {2, 4, 6}
>>> set_one or set_two
{1, 2, 3}
>>> set_one and set_two
{2, 4, 6}
>>> set_one | set_two
{1, 2, 3, 4, 6}
>>> set_one & set_two
{2}
```

When both operands are true/truthy, the boolean operators return the last operand evaluated -- so for `or` it's the first one (the second operand is not evaluated if the first was truthy), and for `and` it's the last one.

The `|` and `&` operators, when applied to sets, perform actual union and intersection operations.

Comment: Thanks alot. Its bad when i forget simple stuff. Wish could accept both answers. Went with the earlie solution.